How to accept 220 V input from this transformer pin?
I'm  confused how make line input accept 220 volt from this transformer. Where the right wiring combination.
I found this transformer from local trash. In my country standard main line voltage is 220 volt. But "220" label not found in primary input.
What I have read from the internet, we can combine wiring to accept variety line input (only 100, 110 and 120).
So, is it possible to wire this transformer to accept 220 volt from main line?


the input is labeled by voltage ... match the line voltage

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you sure that is even a mains voltage transformer? So that is not an transformer for PA system speakers? Also 220 VA is not voltage but power. Do you mean 220V? For what you would need 100V secondary anyway?

@Justme I have edited the question

Please reread Justme's comment. VA is not a unit of voltage.

ops sorry, I have change to volt @Justme

@Justme yes, confirmed is power transformer for machine game

No there isn't a way to make it accept 220V.
Also since you found in from the bin without specification or other context, you don't know if that is a mains voltage transformer or PA system transformer, and you don't know if it is broken or not.

(Probably more useful than mentioning auto-)
